# getAllowWriteReviewFlag() Returns False so Can't write reviews

Tags: magento-1.8, php, review

OK so we're in magento 1.8.1.0 and for some reason the following logic returns false all the time

```
<?php if ($this->getAllowWriteReviewFlag()): ?>
```

Even if I log in, I have the option "System > Configuration > Catalog > Reviews > Allow guests to write reviews" set to true, so technially that function should return true. If I log in, I get the same thing.

Also, I have checked that Mage_Reviews is enabled in System > Config > Developer > advanced

Any ideas?

Comment: where do you call this line of code? What model does it use?

Comment: In which layout file is getAllowWriteReviewFlag() being called?  And has this been defined in the corresponding Block?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using a block that does not inherit that method (function). Instead you could check in the system config object for the setting.

```
$_userCanReview = Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/review/allow_guest');
```

That will return a string of **1** or **0**. Remember that you will also (probably) need to determine whether a user is logged in or not; so that registered and logged-in users can write reviews.

```
$_userLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
```

I'll leave it to you to put together for you own use case.